# Combine data from model into one foreach loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use another solution than the `foreach loop` in the code below to be able to get the values from `Weeks` and `WeekNamesShort` lists within only one `td` tag like this: `<td> @week @monthName </td>` instead of using two separate `td` tags?

Part of the Model:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Weeks { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<string> WeekNamesShort { get; set; }
```

Part of the code in the View:

```
<tr>
<td></td>              
@foreach (var week in project.Weeks)
{
    <th class="week" data-week="@week">@week</th>
}
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
@foreach (var monthName in project.WeekNamesShort)
{
   <td class="week">@monthName</td>
}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could adjust the view model to match the requirements of your view:

```
public class WeekViewModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a `IEnumerable<WeekViewModel>` property:

```
public IEnumerable<WeekViewModel> Weeks { get; set; }
```

and then you can loop:

```
@foreach (var week in project.Weeks)
{
   <td class="week">
       @week.Number
       @week.Name
   </td>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'm not sure how I should use your code. I'm already using a ViewModell class. Where should I place the new list?

Comment: In your project view model, the one that contained the 2 IEnumerable lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same view model, you can use a for loop and the LINQ extension `ElementAt`:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
   <td class="week">
       @Model.Weeks.ElementAt(i)
       @Model.WeekNamesShort.ElementAt(i)
   </td>
}
```